# How to access records of a CMS from one location above where it is installed?

Tags: php, content-management-system, twig, bolt-cms

I use the CMS Bolt and it uses the Twig template engine. I need to access the content created in a page above where the CMS is running.

Example: Bolt installed in the **blog** folder; page to access and display content is the test site **test/blog**.

I'm using this on the page:

```
{% setcontent records = "entries/latest/2" allowpaging %}
{% for record in records %}
   <div class="four columns thumb" style="margin-left: 0px; clear: both";>
      {% if record.image!="" %}
      <img src="{{ thumbnail(record.image, 100, 100) }}" alt="thumbnail" class="u-max-full-width">
      {% endif %}
   </div>
   <div class="eight columns">
      <small class="date">{{ record.datecreated|date("d.m.y") }}</small>
      <p><a href="{{ record.link }}" class="footer_last_blog">{{ record.excerpt(75) }}</a></p>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. What do you mean by "content created in a page above where the CMS is running"? What is a "page" in there?

Comment: @JackWhiteIII it is sad, that this comment seems to become more and more of a habit these days for people who cannot contribute to a question. _Why?_

Comment: I have the CMS inside the folder "/ blog", all the features and calls made to files within that folder are normal, because it is "running" into this directory. But I need to make these funcionalides "rotate" in a directory above, which is not installed CMS. For example in the test folder, one level above the folder blog.You get the idea about? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to link to, links, theme assets etc are all handles slightly differently, however you can always navigate up from a path because the paths always print as strings...

so as well as `{{paths.theme}}/images` you can also do `{{paths.theme}}/../images` and go back a level.

equally you can go one directory up from root via `{{paths.root}}/../`